# Difficult Date Time Conversion in R

Tags: r, datetime, data-cleaning

I'm trying to separate this date/time string in R but have not been successful.
Here is an example of the strings:

"Thu Sep 28 02:11:51 +0000 2017"
"Mon Oct 02 19:22:35 +0000 2017"

What is the best way to make this tidy? I've realized this is far beyond my skills.

Comment: what is the desired format?

Comment: Something universal like this: "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
as.POSIXct(gsub("\\+0000", '', "Thu Sep 28 02:11:51 +0000 2017"), format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

which gives `"2017-09-28 02:11:51 EDT"`

Comment: This may be a dumb question but this converted everything to "2017-09-28 02:11:51 EDT"-- how do I use this to apply to every different date?

Comment: NEVERMIND! I just replaced the hardcoded bad date with the actual variable. Thanks Adam!